# XMLHttp Javascript - How to remove Auto Refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, xmlhttprequest

Hey I have a problem with XMLHttp request. My page will auto refresh every 0.1 second like crazy and I cant stop it.
Im following this tutorial, and the issue seems not covered there.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pZteSkmI9w&list=PL3mtAHT_eRewLlpLhCE8d7Kb6k4g1yA_y

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>My todo list</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;"> Hello from this file </h1>
    <div id="container" style="margin: 2em; border: 2px solid black;">
      Todo #1 : Make the bed
      <br />
      Todo #2 : Record a video
    </div>
</body>

<footer>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="application.js"></script>
</footer>
</html>
```

edit : not application rb.

**application.js**

```
function getTasks() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:3001/todos", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

getTasks();
```

API side I have a Rails API server on 3001 ( I did Rails new .. --webpack=react )

Client side, yet I have only 2 files :

- Index.html ( shown here )
- Application.js ( shown here )

The client page, will just auto refresh non stop like crazy. It actually makes successfull calls, but keep doing them non stop.
Also Im using OpenWithLiveServer ( from VSCode ) on the client side yet.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` never causes a page refresh - it must be something you're doing wrong - and the code you've shown wouldn't cause a single refresh - what's the content of `application.js` - you've shown `application.rb` - is that the *same thing*?

Comment: What could make it auto-refresh ? 
Im opening my index.html file with VSCode + OpenWithLiveServer. Aslo I have a Rails server running on 3001.

Comment: I already said, nothing in what you've *shown* would cause a refresh ... what is in `application.js` though?

Comment: So the API seems fine. It's all about 2 files ( application.js / index.html ).

Comment: Ok I found it.
I just had to reboot VSCode .. lol